# How to enforce trailing slash on everything EXCEPT filenames with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, trailing-slash

I would like to enforce a trailing slash on all URLS except on filenames. Here is my .htaccess file so far.

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)(.+) [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(.+)
RewriteRule ^ https://%2%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index\.php 
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple, check for the condition that the requested file doesn't exist, and redirect:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^.*$ /$0/ [R=301,L,QSA]
```

Note that the above rule set will go just before your `THE_REQUEST` check.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Ran into one problem...

When I go to:
https://example.com/directory/index.php

It redirects to:
    https://example.com/directory // (an extra slash)

Any way to prevent that ?

Answer (score 0):

Have your htaccess like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

# this rule will do 3 things: http->https, www removal, add a trailing slash 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ https://%1/$1/ [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.php$ /$1 [R=301,L,NE,NC]
```